# Converting values in a query

Tags: mysql

In the database I'm using, the following will give me the number of copies for each branch id with the book titled The Lost Tribe.

```
select distinct BC.branch_id, no_of_copies 
from Book_Copies BC, Book B, Library_Branch LB 
where BC.book_id = (select book_id from Book where title = 'The Lost Tribe');
```

But I need to use the corresponding branch names, which is found in the Library_Branch table along with their branch ids. I have no idea how to convert it though, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without really knowing the structure

```
SELECT DISTINCT BC.branch_id, no_of_copies, LB.branch_name 
FROM Book_Copies BC 
LEFT JOIN Book B ON BC.book_id = B.book_id 
LEFT JOIN Library_Branch LB ON BC.branch_id = LB.branch_id 
WHERE B.title = 'The Lost Tribe';
```

FYI you should avoid sub-selects wherever possible.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you :D
Although I'm not entirely sure why it works, I guess I should do some research on left join.

Answer (score 0):

Try INNER JOIN.
From what i realized about the table structure, you can use below.

```
    SELECT branch_id, branch names, no_of_copies
    FROM Library_Branch a
    INNER JOIN Book b ON a.book_id = b.bookID
    WHERE b.book_name = "The Lost Tribe"
```

Use book table and branch table in the inner join and join them with the foreign key.

Comment: Didn't have any luck getting this to work, but thanks.